# Разбить программу на потоки без сторонних библиотек

Tags: c, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Сабж. Понятно, что есть много хороших и разных библиотек для распараллеливания программ на потоки и задачи. А как самому написать библиотеку для многопоточности на голом Си? Что для этого нужно (просто план, пошагово)? Что почитать по этому поводу?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам все равно придется иметь дело с библиотеками. API ОС под которую пишите это и есть библиотека. А всякое разнообразие других библиотек для многопоточности это просто обертки над API. И ещё в самом C нету поддержки многопоточности. Так что ответ ни как не получится на голом С писать многопоточный код. Даже в С++ в новом стандарте многопоточность реализована в стандартной библиотеке, а не в самом языке.

Если хотите писать многопоточный код, то к примеру для *nix систем вам надо по изучать библиотеку pthread.   
Ну а для Windows нужно читать доку по API windows которая отвечает за многопоточность.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy man 2 clone

@Siarshai ну например http://bsvi.ru/protopotoki-protothreads/ (хотя это вовсе и не потоки...)

Comment: @alexlz ну если на то пошло то и API windows тоже написан на чистом C и pthread написан на нем. И при этом они использую возможности ОС для своей реализации.      
А по ссылке там код для микроконтроллеров и эта библиотека как бы представляет мини ОС для контроллеров в которая как бы есть потоки.
С помощью этой библиотеки можно писать якобы многопоточный код но там не понятно когда и как переключается выполнение с потока на поток и не будет настоящей многопоточности на многоядерном контроллере.

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy не protothread -- это скорее сопрограммы, чем потоки. А вот clone -- это вызов ядра, который относится, конечно к libc, но не более.

Comment: @alexlz: в любом случае, если мне не из меняет память, в стандарте C потоков нету, так что придётся пользоваться ОС-специфическими средствами.

Comment: В C, разумеется, никаких потоков нет. А clone -- весьма линуксоспецифичный вызов.

Да и вообще, языкам, в которых есть потоки, лет не так уж и много. Лет пятьдесят, от силы (PL/I,  тип TASK)